# Getting error try to connect firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Hellow all,

I try to connect firebase to my android app but I'm getting this error

[image]

that was triggered I'm tried to sign in to firebase using the assistant tool. I'm tried several solutions here in StackOverflow. but It does not work for me.

this the gradle build project

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here is Gradle build Module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gpacalc.shannirmala.gpacalculator"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
}
```

Comment: I don't see any firebase dependency in your gradle!

Comment: please refer this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: yes, I'm trying to add them using an assistant tool. after successfully done steps automatically add them to gradle buid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring firebase the first time then follow the manual setup because its increase your knowledge second time you can use the assistant tool.

Add Following dependency in Project level `build.gradle` file  like bellow

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0' // google-services plugin
    }
```

Then after apply plugin in your app level `build.gradle` at bottom of your dependency section and also add firebase dependency in dependency section like bellow.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And Finally, put `google-services.json` file in app directory which downloaded from your firebase console after creating firebase project for your application.

[How to create Firebase Project on console?](https://docs.kii.com/en/samples/push-notifications/push-notifications-android-fcm/create-project/)